# Thymeleaf is not rendering authenticated username

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to show the username of the authenticated/logged in user and show LogIn & Singup option when nobody is logged in. I am using the thymeleaf Expression Basic Objects ctx but its not giving me the desired output. The page just shows Login and Signup regardless of the logged in status of a user.

```html
<ul>
  <li th:if="${#ctx.principal==null}">
    <i class="fi-rs-user"></i>
    <a th:href="@{/login}">Log In</a>
  </li>
  <li th:unless="${#ctx.principal==null}">
    <i class="fi-rs-user"></i>
    <span th:text="${principal.username}"></span>
    <a th:href="@{/logout}">Log out</a>
  </li>
  <li th:if="${#ctx.principal==null}">
    <i class="fi-rs-user"></i>
    <a th:href="@{/register}">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: make sure you are not missing `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity` dependency

Answer (score 1):

Second li element`s condition looks wrong, **${#ctx.principal==null}** means if user is **not** logged in and show "Log out" link, it should have been like below.

```html
<ul>
  <li th:if="${#ctx.principal==null}">
    <i class="fi-rs-user"></i>
    <a th:href="@{/login}">Log In</a>
  </li>
  <li th:unless="${#ctx.principal!=null}">
    <i class="fi-rs-user"></i>
    <span th:text="${principal.username}"></span>
    <a th:href="@{/logout}">Log out</a>
  </li>
  <li th:if="${#ctx.principal==null}">
    <i class="fi-rs-user"></i>
    <a th:href="@{/register}">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```